# C++ Protobuf, error when trying to build a FileDescriptor that imports another one

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Currently I have the following two proto definitions, both .proto files are in same folder:
topmessage.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
message TopMessage {
    // some fields
}
```

crestmessage.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "topmessage.proto";
message CrestMessage {
    // some fields
    TopMessage tm = 4;
}
```

Then, as part of my reader.cc, I am trying to build a file descriptor for the proto definition that user passes in. More specifically, the user will pass the path of the .proto file in as an argument, and the program will then read the file and build a file descriptor from it. Here is how this function is implemented, it mainly follows the blog by Floris https://vdna.be/site/index.php/2016/05/google-protobuf-at-run-time-deserialization-example-in-c/:

```
DescriptorPool pool;
const FileDescriptor* buildFileDescriptor(string file_path, string file_name) {
    int def_messageFile = open(file_path.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    FileInputStream file_input(def_messageFile);
    Tokenizer input(&file_input, NULL);
    FileDescriptorProto file_desc_proto;
    Parser parser;
    if (!parser.Parse(&input, &file_desc_proto)) {
        cerr << "Failed to parse .proto definition:" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    file_desc_proto.set_name(file_name);
    const FileDescriptor* file_desc = pool.BuildFile(file_desc_proto);

    return file_desc;
}
```

The question now is when I am trying to build CrestMessage, and its proto definition file is also the one passed in as argument. For simplicity, I first build TopMessage by manually providing its file address since it is the dependency, and it works fine, and I can also find TopMessage in the pool, which is global. However, when I try to build CrestMessage, it gives the error.

```
const FileDescriptor* file_desc2 = buildFileDescriptor("topmessage.proto", "TopMessage");
cout << pool.FindFileByName("TopMessage") << endl;
const FileDescriptor* file_desc = buildFileDescriptor(definition_path, "CrestMessage");
cout << file_desc->name() << endl;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhs5r.png)

I have not find anything in the api description by Google that says how to import, does anyone have ideas on what should be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a name problem, instead of using message name when building FileDescriptor, use the name of the .proto file ("topmessage.proto" for example)